# Проблема с загрузской файла

Tags: база-данных, php, файлы, mysql

Делаю скрипт загрузки файла в базу данных (ну с записью в БД), в чем проблема ребят? Пишет что всё успешно, но поля `name`, `file`, `size` не заполняет и не определяет type. Где я тупанул?

```
 <?
class CFile
{
    public function uploadFile()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $file = $_FILE['upfile'];
            $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['upfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $name = $file['name'];
            $size = $file['size'];
            $user = $_SESSION['usName'];

            //Определим тип файла

            switch ($ext) {
                case 'gif':
                    $type = 'Изображение';
                    break;
                case 'jpg':
                    $type = 'Изображение';
                    break;
                case 'png':
                    $type = 'Изображение';
                    break;
                case 'bmp':
                    $type = 'Изображение';
                    break;
                case 'mp3':
                    $type = 'Аудиозапись';
                    break;
                case 'avi':
                    $type = 'Видеозапись';
                    break;
                case 'mp4':
                    $type = 'Видеозапись';
                    break;
                case '3gp':
                    $type = 'Видеозапись';
                    break;
                case 'flv':
                    $type = 'Видеозапись';
                    break;
                case 'txt':
                    $type = 'Документ';
                    break;
                case 'doc':
                    $type = 'Документ';
                    break;
                case 'xls':
                    $type = 'Документ';
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = 'Файл';
                    break;
            }
            ///////////////////////////

            /******Составим MySQL запрос на запись**************/

            $sql = "
                    INSERT 
                    INTO `files`
                    (`name`, `user`, `type`, `file`, `size`)
                    VALUES 
                    ('$name', '$user', '$type', '$file', 'size')";
            if(mysql_query($sql)) echo '<p class="complited">Файл загружен успешно</p>';
            else die('ERROR: '.mysql_error());

        }

        echo '
            <form method="post" action="" class="iform">
            <ul>
            <li class="iheader">Загрузить файл</li>
            <li><input class="itext" type="file" name="upfile"/></li>
            <li><label>&nbsp;</label><input type="submit" class="ibutton" name="submit" value="Загрузить" /></li>
            </ul>
        ';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: if (in_array($ext, array('gif', 'jpg', 'bmp', 'png',), true)) {
        $type = 'image';
    } elseif (in_array($ext, array('avi', 'mp4', '3gp', 'flv',), true)) {
        $type = 'video';
    } elseif ...

если конкретные расширения вынести и отдельно формировать из них массивы, то код вообще становится идеальным.

Answer (score 1):

вместо `$_FILES['upfile']['name']` напиши  `$_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name']`

Answer (score 0):

Тупанул как обычно :)

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Ну и еще, как я погляжу, может, забыл — переместить-то загруженный файл из uploaddir нужно же

Comment: В смысле переместить? Как?

Comment: Ну, к примеру, так:

    $upload_dir = 'uploads/';
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$upload_dir.$_FILES['upfile']['name']);